# Split a two-dimensional array of js

Tags: javascript

please tell me how to divide a two-dimensional array into N arrays. From this --->

```
{
name: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
price: ['price1', 'price2', 'price3', 'price4']
}
```

need to get this --->

```
[
{name: name1, price: price1}
{name: name2, price: price2}
{name: name3, price: price3}
{name: name4, price: price4}
]
```

on a one-dimensional array, it works

```
    function chunk(arr, size){
      var chunkedArr = [];
      var noOfChunks = Math.ceil(arr.length/size);
      console.log(noOfChunks);
      for(var i=0; i<noOfChunks; i++){
        chunkedArr.push(arr.slice(i*size, (i+1)*size));
      }
       return chunkedArr;
    }
    var chunkedArr = chunk(priceArr, 1);
```

Comment: Small note: it's an object with arrays as values not a two-dimensional array, and you're trying to turn it into an array of objects.

Comment: Your input and output is not valid Javascript either, you will need some `,`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `data.name`, use the `index` provided by `map` to get his buddy-price.

```js
const data = {
    name: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'],
    price: ['price1', 'price2', 'price3', 'price4']
};

const res = data.name.map((name, i) => ({ name, price: data.price[i] }));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then add to each object in the result array. This will work for any number of keys in the input object (and even keys with different length value arrays). Here using [nullish coalescing assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) to ensure an object exists at each index before setting each property.

```js
const input = {
  name: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'],
  price: ['price1', 'price2', 'price3', 'price4'],
};

const result = Object.entries(input).reduce((a, [k, vs]) => {
  for (const [i, v] of vs.entries()) {
    (a[i] ??= {})[k] = v;
  }

  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

---

Mismatched input example

```js
const input = {
  id: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5'],
  name: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'],
  price: ['price1', 'price2'],
};

const result = Object.entries(input).reduce((a, [k, vs]) => {
  for (const [i, v] of vs.entries()) {
    (a[i] ??= {})[k] = v;
  }

  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```